# Lambda em classes relacionadas (EF Migrations)

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, migrations

Faz um tempo que nao mexo com EF por isso a duvida.
Tenha as classes Produto e ProdutoQuantidade e preciso fazer uma consulta nos produtos com quantidade igual a 10;

eu tentei:

```
var retorno = controle.Produto.Where(x => x.ProdutoQuantidade.Total.Equals(10)).toList();
```

Porém já dá erro no ".Total", ele nao encontra nenhuma propriedade da classe ProdutoQuantidade

**[EDITADO]**
Eu mencionei que era acima de 10 por engano, o problema não é o Equal mas nao estava achando as propriedades da classe. Eu já consegui resolver:

```
var retorno = controle.Produto.Where(x => x.ProdutoQuantidade.Any(y => y.Total == 10)).ToList();
```

obrigado
**[EDITADO]**

Comment: se pode colocar as classes `Produto` e `ProdutoQuantidade`? e no lugar de `Equals` coloque `== 10`

Answer (score 0):

Partindo do pressuposto que o a propriedade Total está como INT e que deveria ser acima e não igual a 10 a expressão deveria ser assim.

var retorno = controle.Produto.Where(x => x.ProdutoQuantidade.Total > 10 ).toList();

ou

var retorno = controle.Produto.Where(x => x.ProdutoQuantidade.Total >= 10 ).toList();

O Equals é usado para comparar objetos e não o valor em si, tem um artigo explicando com mais detalhes a diferença de um para o outro.

http://www.macoratti.net/18/06/c_fund1.htm

Comment: agradeço a atençao mas o problema nao era o equal. eu ja achei a solução